# is it a good idea to check in data inserts as part of database solution?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a database project in TFS we usually use the post-deployment script file to     checkin database schema changes. But recently I needed to do a bunch of Insert statements to the database. So my questions should I keep these insert statements in the database project or do the insert directly to the database? I know one point might be to keep track of changes to the database but do we really need to track inserts?

Comment: Surely you need to script your inserts.  When you deploy to UAT/PROD etc. you will want to insert the same data right?  If you don't script it, how will it be done?  Never manually, that would be very scary.

Comment: I guess I wasn't scared much to do a manual insert. Thanks Though.

Comment: May be I didnt see the difference of doing it manually and deploying the database solution. After all we get the same effect on the DB. The only difference I saw was Tracking changes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you MUST maintain these INSERT scripts in TFS. They help a lot if you want to keep track of changes in a long-running project.

Comment: `Must` is very subjective.  I know plenty of people that appear to enjoy making their own lives painful.  `Beneficial` I agree with, especially to other that follow on with maintenance or development, but `must` doesn't account for innate stupidity :)

Comment: Thanks Guys, what kind of side effects can you mention beside tracking the changes? The reason I am saying is either the database deployment or the manual insert will have the same effect on the database even on the production database. The only advantage I found is we will get additional validation on the development server beside local before we push our changes to production.

Comment: Tracking changes is the most important advantage that you get out of this process and it really helps in a long-running project. Its becomes too much of an overhead in a short-term project but it really helps in a long-term project.